# maven compile encoding puzzle

Tags: maven, jenkins

Ok, I'm baffled,
I'm getting the following compilation error

```
.../Currency.java:[16,60] unmappable character for encoding ASCII
```

i have set the encoding in the maven conf settings using

```
<properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<properties>
```

here is the build output

```
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting directory /export/jenkins_slave/workspace/Agent-Transfer/repo/foo-bar-   api/target
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 10 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 59 source files to /export/jenkins_slave/workspace/Agent- Transfer/repo/foo-bar-api/target/classes
[JENKINS] Archiving /export/jenkins_slave/workspace/Agent-Transfer/repo/foo-bar-  api/pom.xml to /export/ciserver/.hudson/jobs/Agent-Transfer/modules/com.cdc$foo-bar-  api/builds/2012-03-31_14-49-02/archive/com.cdc/foo-bar-api/Agent-Transfer-SNAPSHOT/foo-bar-  api-Agent-Transfer-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

/export/jenkins_slave/workspace/Agent-Transfer/repo/foo-bar-api/src/main/java/com/cdc/games/domain/Currency.java:[16,60] unmappable character for encoding ASCII
```

I know that the encoding is being picked up from the settings.xml because if i remove it get the encoding warning

```
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (ISO8859-1 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
```

The problems is it only seems - from the log out put above - to have an effect on resources:resources and not on compile:compile. I was expecting from the description on [the wiki](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#encoding) for this to encode the .java files

as you can see i'm building this on a slave, on the master it builds even with the encoding warning, but i guess thats because the platform encoding is different.  I could change that on the slave, but i would rather not as i want the builds to be portable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using an editor that does not acknowledge Mavens character encoding when you are typing and it picks up some other platform or editor dependent encoding? It may look correct in the editor, but it seems like some strange character has sneaked into the code by accident. Have you tried to delete line 16 in the Currency.java class and rewrite it (without using copy / paste)?

Comment: There some are characters in a string that are not ascii, but i was expecting the UTF-8 setting on the maven compile plugin to be able to handle it

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem a couple times supporting multiple instances of hudson/jenkins. In my case, it turned out that the LANG env var was not explicitly set to en_US.UTF-8 **in the hudson/jenkins configuration**.

Once I set that Global environment var for the hudson/jenkins installation my java files containing unicode characters stopped giving me an error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.resources.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.resources.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

[source](http://www.bermione.be/technology/maven-and-utf-8/)

and in your server.xml

```
     <Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you got this working, because it's been a year... but in

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<properties>
```

That last  is incorrect.  Should be `</properties>`, right?